# More aesthetic way to instantiate an anonymous implementation of a trait

Tags: scala, anonymous-class, traits

Say I have a function that expects an instance of a trait:

```
trait MyTrait[T] {
  def f1: T
  def f2(t: T): Unit
}

def foo[T](t: MyTrait[T]) { ... }
```

Now, anywhere I call this function I need to use the following syntax:

```
val x = foo[String](new MyTrait[String] {
  def f1 = "Hello"
  def f2(str: String) = { ... }
}
```

I am wondering if there is another way I can achieve this to make my usages simpler and more aesthetic? Ideally I would like to have the following usage:

```
val x = foo() {
  def f1 = "Hello"
  def f2(str: String) = { ... }
}
```

Comment: Note also that you don't need to specify the type parameter of `foo[T]` when you call it, as this will be inferred from the type parameter of the instance of `MyTrait` that you pass in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use this trait anonymous everywhere like you described, throw it away!
Instead make the function look like

```
def foo[T](f1: T,  f2: T => Unit)
```

so you can call it like

```
foo("Hello", (myString:String) =>  { } )
```

Comment: In which programming language does the code example, which you showed here, compile?

Comment: Sorry, did it in a hurry :( Corrected it ;)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to Nabil A.'s answer, if you want to keep the trait, is to subclass it using a case class that takes `f1` and (a function describing) `f2` as parameters:

```
case class MyClass[T](f1: T, _f2: T => Unit) extends MyTrait[T] {
  def f2(t: T) = _f2(t)
}
```

You can then instantiate it as:

```
foo(MyClass[String]("hello", str => {...}))
```